# Why does CSS not allow me to nest selector blocks?

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-class

I'm just trying to create another dropdown menu effect within a dropdown menu.

Observe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/class-lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="selected">Parent 02</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 01</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="selected">Item 02</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 03</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div> <!--".clear" div is nested within the .selected class, outside of the <ul>. Does this provide a buffer??? -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Parent 03</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a name="child" href="#">Child 04</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 01</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 02</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 03</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 05</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 06</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 07</a></li>
        </ul>         
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Parent 04</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>>
```

CSS:

```
#nav li ul li a:hover{

                #nav li ul li ul li a{
                        visibility:visible;   /*<-- the only reason why I did that was to see if something like this would actually work. It doesn't. I gotta say I'm really not a fan of this language. While I'm sure there were reasons for not implementing this kind of method and design/scripting pattern, it seems like there are just as well plenty reasons TO implement it. */  
                }
        }

        #nav li ul li ul{
        display:block;
        list-style:none;
        }

        #nav li ul li ul li{
        float:right;
        clear:both;
        width:50px;
        height:100px;
        background:#000;
        }

        #nav li ul li ul li a{
        visibility:hidden;
        color:#fff;
        }
```

The only reason why I did that was to see if something like this would actually work. It doesn't. I gotta say I'm really not a fan of this language. While I'm sure there were reasons for not implementing this kind of method and design/scripting pattern, it seems like there are just as well plenty reasons TO implement it.

Why does CSS not allow me to nest selector blocks?

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? We are not sitting here to observe your WALL OF CODE. Tell the problem in brief.

Comment: Hopefully my changes made the question a question. @Holland, correct me if that's not question you want to ask, but we can't really read minds...

Comment: @Blender: did you really just do that?

Comment: @Blender: Wow.... that was amazing.

Comment: Just do what? I'm too lazy to write ;) I copied the OP's enormous CSS comment (which made a pretty valid paragraph) and tacked it onto the end.

Comment: @Blender: ahhh ok. I thought you literally just assumed Hollands identity and filled in the rest of the question. I get it now.

Comment: I tried, so if I failed, then @Hollard can always rollback and correct the post, as we are not really able to understand it...

Comment: @Holland's gone to holland to search the question's meaning? Atleast reply.

Comment: @Holland - don't feel bad about wanting more from your CSS, you are, or rather were, in good company: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing:

```
#nav li ul li a:hover{

                #nav li ul li ul li a{
                        visibility:visible; 
                }
}
```

It should be:

```
#nav li ul li:hover ul li a
{
    visibility:visible; 
}
```

Comment: + 1 for having the bravery & patience to sift through this without much of a clue as to what was needed.

Comment: I thought I made my point relatively clear, but either way there was no need for anyone to freak out over how I asked the question. A simple "can you be more specific?" would have sufficed. If it was because of the comment I made about CSS, I still stand firmly there: I think it's design is shit.

Comment: @Andre:

Thank you, I'll put that to good use I'm sure.

Comment: Well, then 99% of the web is shit ;) CSS is great at what it does, like Linux utilities. A text editor doesn't need a web browser and a music player in it, as that's not the intended purpose. CSS is the same way. It's a do-what-I-say language for browsers to skim over and quickly apply to the webpage. JavaScript is for logic. CSS is for doing things.

Comment: Ok, you make a good point: I'll make an effort to be more open minded here. Anyway, sorry for the b.s. I'll be sure to be more specific next time.

Comment: No problem. CSS does take a while to get used to (at least for me it did), as it is almost a language, but more like a configuration file...

Comment: But if you want to look at CSS-like language (which you parse into CSS via a Ruby program), take a look at [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). It supports nesting, like you want.

Comment: ....Wow. CSS just became...cool.

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest statements. It's just not the right use for CSS.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets):

> Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is a
>   **style sheet language used to describe
>   the presentation semantics (the look
>   and formatting) of a document** written
>   in a markup language. Its most common
>   application is to style web pages
>   written in HTML and XHTML, but the
>   language can also be applied to any
>   kind of XML document, including plain
>   XML, SVG and XUL.

CSS isn't a scripting language like JavaScript, so it doesn't behave like one. It just tells the browser what to display and how to display it. That's just the main purpose of it.

There *are* ways, though, to do what you want in pure CSS. While you can't nest rule declarations, you can still apply them in nifty ways:

```
element subelement {
  display: none;
}

element:hover subelement {
  display: block;
}
```

That's the basic logic behind a dropdown menu in pure CSS. Think of `:hover` as a thing which adds a class to the element being hovered and work from there.

If you want a full tutorial, here's a promising one: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that one out.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have shown you how to fix the problem, but you shouldn't really be doing it that way anyways; although it is a nice and clean way to create menus, it crosses the boundaries in the content-presentation-behaviour rule. Although it may not matter much, the code that drops down menus belongs in JavaScript.