# Why CSS class is made such that it can't contain another CSS class

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, css, web

Why one CSS class can't contain another CSS class
e.g.

```
.parentCSS width:100% childCSS
```

I really have many duplicate entries in my file because of this

Somewhere on the aspx page (one control many CSS classes) and somewhere in the CSS file (one CSS class many duplicate attributes).

Any suggestion to write proper CSS if CSS nesting is unachievable would be very helpful.

Comment: ummm Can you rephrase the question?  Your title and question are just about exactly the same for the most part...

Comment: Ask the W3c. Voting to close. But I will agree that it would be nice to able to nest classes and have them TRULY cascade in the style sheet as well as in the DOM.

Comment: yeah, guys from google feel your pain - so they created a proposal for css4, to allow nesting - http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-hierarchies/#motivation (_yet, this is a very early draft_)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195857/why-does-css-not-allow-me-to-nest-selector-blocks

Comment: @c69 good news , hope they'll bring it ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because CSS wasn't build that way, it doesn't support nesting, however there is a plugin http://lesscss.org/ that allow you to create stylesheets in a more flexible way.

> LESS extends CSS with dynamic behavior such as variables, mixins,
>   operations and functions. LESS runs on both the client-side (Chrome,
>   Safari, Firefox) and server-side, with Node.js and Rhino.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is but css does allow this:

```
.parent,
.parent .child {
    /* css */
}
```

Comment: this way CSS allow to add attribute to multiple classes in one statement, not child css to parent css.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to explicitly name all classes:

```
.parentCSS .childCSS { width:100% }
.childCSS { height:100% }
```

Or combine them in markup:

```
<div class="parentCSS childCSS"></div>
```

Probably would be helpful to show details/examples of what you're trying to do.

Comment: it's most helpful to post the actual HTML/CSS you're using.